# XML Conversion to CSV

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I need to convert some XML to a CSV file using an XSLT file. The XML code is listed in abbreviated form below.  The CSV format I'm looking for is
hostName,generationDate,machineId

Example of required CSV

```
DESKTOP-H3B7ONO,20171014T100948Z,3A80-071084
```

I only require 3 values from the XML file and the rest can be ignored.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<document>
  <properties>
    <basic>
      <property id="hostName">
        <value>DESKTOP-H3B7ONO</value>
      </property>
      <property id="generationDate">
        <value>20171014T100948Z</value>
      </property>
      <property id="rotationType">
        <value></value>
      </property>
      <!-- ... many properties omitted here ... -->
      <property id="generationEpoch">
        <value>1507975788796</value>
      </property>
      <property id="machineId">
        <value>3A80-071084</value>
      </property>
      <property id="application">
        <value>scan</value>
      </property>
      <!-- ... more properties omitted ... -->
    </basic>
  </properties>
</document>
```

There is only one record in the input (the `basic` element does not repeat).

I have tried the following stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Utf-8" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                version="1.0"> 
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="Utf-8" /> 

  <xsl:template match="basic"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="property"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="value" />
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text> 
      <xsl:text></xsl:text> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So do you need one line with those three values or do you expect there to be several of those three elements? In the latter case, are they siblings or is there a new `basic` parent for any "record/line" of those three elements you are interested in? And what have you tried? Selecting elements with XPath is covered in any XPath tutorial.

Comment: There is only one record and all is in the basic, im only interested in those 3 elements, i have tried the below 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="Utf-8" />
<xsl:template match="basic">
<xsl:for-each select="property">
<xsl:value-of select="value" /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:text></xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Note to close-voters:  I am unable to think of any way to understand this question and not understand it as a question about programming within the scope statement at the help center.  Would you please explain?  The question describes a specific programming problem involving tools (here: XSLT as a programming language) commonly used by programmers, and the problem is practical and answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.

Instead of the `xsl:for-each` in your stylesheet, you might try

```
<xsl:value-of select="property[@id='hostName']/value"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="property[@id='generationDate']/value"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="property[@id='machineId']/value"/>
```